# Image appearing in tauri dev build but not in final build

Tags: reactjs, rust, tsx, tauri

I am trying to build a desktop app with Tauri. I want to include an icon for a back button. Here is my file structure

[image: My file structure]

This works in the dev build, when I run `npm run tauri dev`. However this image is not displayed in the final build. I tried including it in "resources" in tauri.conf.json, which did not help. I am using react for the front end.

Here is how I am importing the image.

```
  <img className="clickable" id="back" src="src/public/icons/back.png"></img>
```

ChatGPT is being no help, just repeatedly telling me to include it in the resources list, which i have done:
[image: Ugh]

When I install the built app (im on windows btw) my public folder is there, with the image inside, but the front end just doesnt seem to be able to find it.

Im completely new to tauri and react. Ive been trying for ages to find a solution, and im sure its super simple and I'll kick myself. Thanks guys for any help/input you can give, please ask any questions if i wasnt clear enoguh.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE], otherwise we can't help you I'm afraid.